# python pandas: group by condition on rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe from which I'm trying to form pairs for some rows.

My df looks as follows:

```
object_id increment location event
        0         1        d     A
        0         2        d     B
        0         3        z     C
        0         4        g     A
        0         5        g     B
        0         6        i     C
        1         1        k     A
        1         2        k     B
      ...       ...      ...  ...
```

Object ids describe a specific object. 
Increment is a value that increments every time something happens (to keep track of the order), location is the location at which this thing happens. And the last column is the type of event.

Now, I want to group these as sometimes (but not always) when A happens at a location, B happens after that, and then C is a completely different event and can be ignored. But I only want to group these together when the location is the same, the object id is the same, and when the events are listed right after each other (so the increment should only differ by 1).

Now the problem is that these events and increment numbers start from zero again for the same object at some times. So I only want to group them when they are exactly located after each other in the dataframe (so groups should contain two entries at max). I'm having a really hard time pulling this off as there are no options of comparing rows in the `groupby` function.

Any tips what direction I should try?

edit: 
The output I'm looking for is forming groups of the form:

```
group_id object_id increment location event
       0         0         1        d     A
       0         0         2        d     B
       1         0         3        z     C
       2         0         4        g     A
       2         0         5        g     B
       3         0         6        i     C
       4         1         1        k     A
       4         1         2        k     B
     ...       ...       ...      ...   ...
```

So only forming groups when the "first" entry of the pair has event A and some increment value x, and the "second" entry has event B and increment value x+1, and is therefore part of the same sequence. Hope this clarifies my question a bit!

Comment: its not clear for me, could you post the result you want?

Comment: edited my original post

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, so in this question you might need to work on the conditions in the if statement, however this might help you.

The dataframe set up:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'object_id': [0,0,0,0], 'increment': [1,2,3,4],
     'location': ['d', 'd', 'z', 'g'], 'event': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Let's make a list to save the index where the location is the same. Furthermore you should add the conditions in the way that work for you but that was not so clear from your question. From there you can run the following function:

```
lst = []
def functionGrouping(dataset):
    for i in range(len(df)-1):
        if df['event'].iloc[i+1] == 'C':
            i = i + 1
        else:
            if df['location'].iloc[i+1] == df['location'].iloc[i] and df['object_id'].iloc[i+1] == df['object_id'].iloc[i]:
                df['increment'].iloc[i+1] = df['increment'].iloc[i+1]  + df['increment'].iloc[i] 
                lst.append([i])

functionGrouping(df)
```

And from there drop the rows which you summed up in the function.

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    df=df.drop(df.index[i])
```

I hope that this helped a bit, however your question was not really clear. For future questions, please simplify your question and include an example of the desired output.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my original response with some more context. But your reply already helped me a lot!